# Dreamweaver does not define a PHP function

Tags: php, dreamweaver

For some reason, my Dreamweaver CC does not recognize the PHP instruction 'function'. It should highlight it in green, but it does not (uses the same brownish-grey as for other unknown instructions). Wherever I try to define a function inside the script, it does not recognize the instructions as it should. I searched everywhere, noone seems to have had the same problem. The way to define a function on PHP has not changed. Is there an explanation that does not include reinstalling Dreamweaver?

The script and WAMP server are correctly working. All other instructions work fine.
An example:

```
if (!function_exists('whatever'))
{
function whatever() // 'function' not recognized as valid PHP instruction
{
//stuff
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, *"Wherever I try to define a function inside the script, it does not recognize the instructions as it should."*? That isn't a useful problem description. What are you expecting? What actually happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: This is an application configuration issue and not a programming related problem.

Comment: Ask their support. That works correctly in CS4 so I'd think it should work in the newer versions.

Comment: Does the code in the function block run at all either locally or on a server? If so, then it merely a software configuration problem not a programming problem. If the answer to that was 'no' then there maybe some other underlying problem that needs to be addressed first.